# How to fix undefined reference to TIFFOpen-TIFFClose-TIFFGetFiled on Ubuntu-19.04

Tags: image-processing, cmake, qt5, opencv3.0, libtiff

I have recently installed `Ubuntu-19.04`. I saved the the most important data from `Ubuntu-18.04` as an enormous `.tar` file as I had some broken files on my 18.04 and transferred everything to the new 19.04 so that I had the same exact layout/folders/data I had before. In this process of course some libraries/dependencies were lost and had to reinstall them.

On my computer I have `CMake 3.13.4` from official documentation,`Qt5` installed from official documentation,`OpenCV 3.4.4` installed from [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-4-4-on-ubuntu-18-04/).

Almost all libraries and dependencies are restored, however I get the last three errors after launching `CMake` and `Qt5`:

`/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/liblibCam.so: undefined reference to TIFFOpen`

`/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/liblibCam.so: undefined reference to TIFFClose`

`/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/liblibCam.so: undefined reference to TIFFGetField
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I am not sure if this compilation error is due to `OpenCV`. I installed fresh the following libraries: `libtiff5` and `libtiff5-dev` but still the problem remains.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/auhhs904gnx2mla/compilerError-2019-08-11_20.50.45.mp4?dl=0) you can find the video of the error I recorded from the screen if that is easier to understand.

Any idea why is not compiling successfully?

Comment: “Launching CMake”. What are you trying to build? I have no idea what you’re trying to do here, you’ll have to give a lot more information. The only thing I see is that liblibCam needs libTiff, but you’re not linking to it, or it’s not found.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, thank you very much for taking the time to read my question. The most important data I saved were in `/home` and those are the ones that I copied. I copied the whole folder into an external server and put it back after the installation was successful. No `sudo apt-get upgrade` but a clean installation of 19.04. My `CMake` works fine and it parses the project successfully, My `Qt5` works very well. However when it comes the time to `compile` the project my `CMake` stops almost right away and throws the error.

Comment: In my `ubuntu-18.04` I had `libtiff4`, are you suggesting that I install `libtiff4` instead of `libtiff5`? Do you think that the old version is keeping `CMake` from compiling?

Comment: As I said, there’s no way of knowing what is wrong, I don’t even know *what* you’re trying to compile. You need to give a whole lot more information than this.

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/auhhs904gnx2mla/compilerError-2019-08-11_20.50.45.mp4?dl=0) you can find the video of the error I recorded from the screen if that is easier to understand. This project is too big to share and I cannot ask you to go through the code. The only think it comes to my mind is to share the `mp4` video I made of the whole process+error. It is about a processing images pipeline I am building